# what is purpose of Binding an Attribute to NameColumn and Binding an Attribute to KeyColumn?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I recently started learning SSAS. While trying to understand the Attribute properties, I came across two features under the source tab:

1. KeyColumn
2. Name Column; when browsed about them in microsoft SSAS documentation, I came across

"Bind An Attribute to a Name Column" and "Bind an Attribute to a Key Column" .

Can anyone help me understand what exactly is the objective with each of the Binding task?

Below are the links for the documentation source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/attribute-properties-bind-an-attribute-to-a-key-column?view=asallproducts-allversions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/attribute-properties-bind-an-attribute-to-a-name-column?view=asallproducts-allversions

Thank you for giving your valuable time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest this link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3271/sql-server-analysis-server-ssas-keycolumn-vs-namecolumn-vs-valuecolumn/

Comment: Hello Subbu, Thank you for giving your time. I have gone through the information on the link you referred to me; however, I have some concerns which I elaborated them in a document and shared them as images in my original post just a while ago. Would you please go through them when you to opportunity?